# Error in Decimal variable to text datatype comparison

Tags: ms-access, vb6, decimal

While comparing  variable with data from ADODB.Recordset  gives results as tabulated below:

- AssYear string variable = “2022-2023”
- rs1!FromAY     text column in mssaccess = “2020”
- typename(rs1!FromAY)                    -  Field

  ```
   Double(variable in vb6) and text(datatype in mdb)
   val(Mid(AssYear, 1, 4)) >= rs1!FromAY                   TRUE

   Decimal(variable in vb6) and text(datatype in mdb)
   cdec(Mid(AssYear, 1, 4)) >= rs1!FromAY                  FALSE
  ```

While comparing Decimal variable and text(datatype in mdb) via ADODB.Recordset  it returns false(incorrect result) but for Double variable and text(datatype in mdb) comparison it returns true.

I can't use Double due to roundoff error.
How to compare Decimal variable to text in ADODB.Recordset ?

The below methods works. what is the reason for the above error?

```
cdec("2022") >= cdec(rs1!FromAY)                        TRUE
cdec("2022") >= cstr(rs1!FromAY)                        TRUE
```

Comment: You have a working method, why are you asking for another?

Comment: If you are comparing numbers (or even dates) by the looks of it, I wonder why you're using string variables and columns of string type in the DB? You make your life harder than it needs to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
CDec(Mid("2022-2023", 1, 4)) >= "2020"
```

so try with:

```
CDec(Mid(AssYear, 1, 4)) >= rs1!FromAY.Value
```

or:

```
CDec(Mid(AssYear, 1, 4)) >= Val(rs1!FromAY.Value)
```

But no reason to use `CDec` here. So, as you wish to compare integer numbers, why not:

```
Val(Mid(AssYear, 1, 4)) >= Val(rs1!FromAY.Value)
```

Comment: both cdec("2022") >= cdec(rs1!FromAY)  - Numerical Comparison
and   cstr("2022") >= cstr(rs1!FromAY) - string comparison  works .
So what is reason for error?

Comment: Perhaps the left out of property `.Value`.

Comment: .Value method not working.

Comment: Then some values are _Null_ or of a different format from what you posted.